# Run python in external terminal in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-code-runner

I have just installed and set up python in VS Code. I am using code-runner extension to run it but it runs in integrated terminal. I want it to run in external terminal. I know I have to place a statement in code-runner.executorMap because I did so for C and Cpp.

Although there is another solution to open external terminal and run the code there manually but I want to set up this thing with code-runner because it compiles and executes the code simply with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>.

I looked for solution on google. I found a few but they were not working.

Comment: You need to change it from settings!  Go to VS Code Settings > Search "terminal" in Settings  > then Change Explorer Kind from Integrated to External and You're Done.

Comment: @AbrahimZaman360 The thing you mentioned just opens a file from file explorer into integrated/external terminal. What I have mentioned in question is that I press **ctrl + alt + N** and want it to automatically compile and run the program in external terminal. I have done so with C and Cpp.